# Wildfly deploy and launch command line (JavaEE and Kafka)

Tags: java, deployment, apache-kafka, wildfly

I've been struggling with deploy on Wildfly and can't find an answer (maybe I'm looking to it wrongly).

So my goal is to deploy an app that works on two ways :

- REST API
- Kafka processes (Producers / Consumers / Streams)

I want to give my users the way to push me informations to feed some streams, whereas I'll have producers running alongside to fetch data from different datasources.

For now, I'm succesfully compiling my WAR file, API is accessible and i can run my command lines to launch my many processes but I wan't to make it automatic on deployment.

Anything I can look at? So far I haven't found anything about it.

Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Use spark and expose its jetty API. It has a seamless integration with Kafka and streams therein

Comment: What are you trying to make automatic?

Comment: The many  "java -cp xxx" command lines to run my kafka producers / consumers.